# Using spacy in Google app script returns error

Tags: google-apps-script, spacy

I would like to build an app in Google Apps Script to recognize similar responses from a google form.

For measuring the similarity of two text data, I use [space-js](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-js), and here is the code to test it:

```
function myFunction() {
    const spacy = require('spacy');
    const nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm');
    apples, and_, oranges = nlp('apple and oranges');
    Logger.log(apples)
}
```

But then I received the following error:

```
ErrorReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Seem like I cannot use spacy-js in Google app script. So are there any way to get around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, `require` cannot be used with Google Apps Script. I thought that when the script of `space-js` can be run with Google Apps Script, you might be able to use it by directly copying and pasting the script of `space-js` to the script editor. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want to use it in Apps Script you can just copy and paste the library.

You can find the source code for the current distribution of the library here:

https://github.com/ines/spacy-js/blob/master/dist/index.js

Just copy everything there and paste it into a new file in the script editor. Then you should be able to use it as if you have already imported it.

#### However

It seems that to run this particular library you will need a Python server to compute the values, which may be more complicated seeing as Apps Script does not run Python. Though if your server is accessible to public, you could use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), but you will probably have to modify some settings or the way that spacy.js comminicates with the server.

So I would think that, especially if you are just developing for now, to run your JS locally in your browser, that will make communication with a local python server much easier.